# Instead of replacing the object it adds a new one in a nested array with React

Tags: reactjs

Sup,

So I have this object:

```js
data: {
OtherFields: {},
Skills: [
      {
        id: Math.random(),
        name: 'Default Category',
        skills: [],
      },
    ],
{
```

So the Skills Array is very dynamic, I need to add categories, and each categories have their own array named skills, that will be filled with other objects, and the default category is there.

While the skills inside will have:

```
{
   id: Math.random(),
   skillName: 'Default Category',
}
```

What I want to do is add the skill to the specific category in a dynamic way with the id category as we don't know how much the user will add.

Here what I did until now:

```js
const handleAdd = (id, content) => {
    // id is the cateogry of that specific cateogry that im receiving from input
    // content is the value of the input


    // this is the object i need to push into the category
    const newItem = {
      id: Math.random(),
      skillName: content,
    };

    // and then update it,
    const newData = data.Skills.find((i) => i.id === id);
    console.log(newData)
    newData.skills.push(newItem);
    setData({ ...data, Skills: [...data.Skills, newData] });

    //this it works but adds another cateogry and doesnt not replace the current one with the new value that is added
  };
```

Comment: not a good idea having two different members with the same name. Give one of them a (slightly) different name. Your code will be more clear.

Comment: @MarioVernari what do you mean with that more exactly

Comment: You have "Skills" and "skills". If the outer one represents a collection of "skill", why you have another collection of "skill" inside? that puzzles who is watching your code. You could rename the outer one to "SkillCategories", for instance. However, mine is just a suggestion: nothing related to the problem you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

This appends `newData` to the array:

```
Skills: [...data.Skills, newData]
```

But it doesn't filter that same record from the array when appending it.  It basically means "the whole array as-is, plus this new element".  Even if that element is *conceptually* a duplicate, the code doesn't know that.  (Heck, even if it's *by reference* a duplicate, there's still nothing stopping an array from containing two references to the same object.)

It sounds like you want to filter that whole array to remove that element before re-appending it.  For example:

```
Skills: [...data.Skills.filter(s => s.id !== newData.id), newData]
```

Comment: Wow this worked well, accepting it.

Comment: But we do have a problem with this approach, for example I'm mapping the values, and when a new one is added, it goes down to the list, the catch is to do it on that spot and not remove the old one add add the new one. @David

Comment: @rehipex378: In that case the other posted answer should work as well.  I personally find it sometimes less intuitive to rely on modifying object references like that, particularly when talking about React state.  You might also want to not rely on default array ordering.  An array is just data, nothing more.  If you want it to be in a specific order then you should sort it when rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're modifying the original object this should work, rename your variables to make it easier to read.

Also consider not changing the original object.

`setData({ ...data, Skills: [...data.Skills] });`

Comment: Does it replace the value or edits the exiting, if it adds one then it will add to the bottom, and the positon will switch for example if it is on the first line it will go at the bottom, and i don't want this I want to stay at the same place